# Picking images from any gallery suddenly stopped working

Tags: android, android-studio

my app has suddenly started crashing after trying to pick an image from any gallery.
It has been working with this same code for a very long time. I prepared it for android 11 lately and after I finished editing the code, it still worked. Today it decided to throw this exception:

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20200915-WA0003.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.file.to.text, PID: 6149
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/63620/ORIGINAL/NONE/image/jpeg/2126822588 flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F63620/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fjpeg/2126822588} }} to activity {*mypackagename*/*mypackagename*.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4846)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4887)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7403)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
        at com.file.to.text.MainActivity.getBase64String(MainActivity.kt:171)
        at com.file.to.text.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.kt:138)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4839)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4887) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7403) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

I don't know what is causing it, the permissions to read from the external storage and write to the external storage are allowed and this exception is caused with every gallery.

I'm testing on a device with stock Android 10.

I've been using this code in my app to pick images galleries:

```
fun pickimage(view: View) {
    //val getIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    //getIntent.type = "image/*"
    val pickIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
    pickIntent.type = "image/*"
    //val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(getIntent, "Select Image")
    //chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, arrayOf(pickIntent))
    startActivityForResult(pickIntent, PICK_IMAGE)
    pic.isEnabled = false
}
```

The onActivityResult():

```
public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                val selectedImage = data!!.data
                val picturePath = getPath(applicationContext, selectedImage)
                val encoded = getBase64String(picturePath, press) //press - some integer
            }
        }
}
```

The getBase64String():

```
private fun getBase64String(path: String, press: Int): String {
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path)
        val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, press, byteArrayOutputStream)
        val byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT)
}
```

I would gladly appreciate any help.

Comment: Throw away that getPath() function. You can use the obtained uri directly to open an inputstream and use the stream in decodeStream() instead. You will be ready for Android 11 then too.

Comment: @blackapps Thank you so much, works perfectly. I have a small question, I use the getPath() function to also get the size of the images and set the integer "press" accordingly, how can I get the size of the image without this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Uri uri = data.getData();   

String projection [] = {

          MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
        , MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME
        , MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE};
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

if ( cursor==null)
{
    Toast.makeText(context, "cursor==null\n\ncould not query content resolver for\n\n" + uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
    return;
}

cursor.moveToFirst();
String data = cursor.getString(0);
String displayName = cursor.getString(1);
String size = cursor.getString(2);

Toast.makeText(context, "query() ok\n\n" + uri.toString()
            + "\n\nDISPLAY_NAME: " + displayName
            + "\nDATA: " + data
            + "\nSIZE: " + size
            , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
cursor.close();
```